# How I can run a private Waves blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, truffle, ganache, wavesplatform, ride

How to run private Waves blockchain for development, are there any tools like Ganache/Truffle for Waves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called [Dev Toolkit](https://github.com/wavesplatform/dev-toolkit), it allows to run private blockchain, block explorer, client, etc.